# Logs with Pino not showing in Datadog APM trace logs

Tags: node.js, express, datadog, pinojs

I'm having trouble getting Pino logs to show up in Datadog APM traces, even though, it would appear that the log injection is working fine.

So I have `dd-trace` all running fine, and traces and spans appearing perfectly in APM. I then hook up Pino, I have all env vars set correctly and when my Pino log outputs I can see the `trace_id` and `span_id` in the log... but under Logs in APM I see nothing.

My Pino log looks like this:

```json
{
  "level":30,
  "time":1658480164226,
  "pid":20400,
  "hostname":"local",
  "dd":{
    "trace_id":"1314152611599688171",
    "span_id":"6560268894829180062",
    "service":"datadog-sandbox",
    "version":"development",
    "env":"development"
  },
  "foo":"bar",
  "msg":"How am I doing?"
}
```

As you can see, the `trace_id` and `span_id` have been injected in to the log. But when I look at this trace and span in APM I see no logs connected at all:

[image: APM Trace]

Am I missing some configuration here? I'm happy to supply any other code if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: I must note I am in the development environment... could this be why? It will not send to APM in development?

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Nope, still not solved it.

Answer (score 0):

`dd-trace` is just injecting the tracing context into the logs in order to correlate between traces and logs. It does not send the logs anywhere on its own.

Logs sending can be achieved by Datadog Agent or directly via HTTP. I was able to make it work with [Agentless logging](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/nodejs/?tab=winston30#agentless-logging)

Comment: Yep, the thing is we are using an agent. I am using the offical Datadog docker agent locally and we have our own agent running in production... but still, not logs are appearing.